# NoMethodError when requesting attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a model (Listing) with a city_id attribute.

In the rails console, I can do something like this:

```
@listing = Listing.where(id: 65)
```

This returns the attributes of the Listing object with id 65, as expected. This Listing's city_id = 3.

However, when I run this...

```
@listing.city_id
```

I get this error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `city' for # <Listing::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f1783ecc560>
```

This is a problem as I'm trying to geocode listings by a combo of address + city. It's not just an issue with requesting the city_id attribute though, it also doesn't work for any other attribute (even though when I request @listing by itself I can see that these attributes have values).

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Listing.rb

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :city
has_many :reviews

accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews, :allow_destroy => true
acts_as_votable
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "700x500>", :thumb =>    "300x200>" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
acts_as_punchable
after_create  :update_sitemap

geocoded_by :geocode_address
after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?

def geocode_address
  [address, city].compact.join(', ')
end

end
```

Comment: can you post your listing.rb file, it could lack the relationship between Listing and City.

Comment: using ``@listing = Listing.where(id: 65).first`` as mentioned by @j-plato should fix ur issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@listing = Listing.where(id: 65)
```

returns a relation (see the error message you're getting).  You need

```
@listing = Listing.where(id: 65).first
```

to get the individual listing

Comment: Ah, okay. This works. So my issue is not what I thought it was then. I suppose this is a problem with how I have setup geocoder.

Comment: Not sure, but this isn't necessarily indicative of a problem with your geocoder setup.  Just bear in mind that where() always returns a relation, since there could be more than one matching record (not when searching for :id, of course, but where() doesn't know that).  If you're sure that the where() should only return one record with the parameters your're passing, follow it with a call to first().  Otherwise, loop through the records in the relation with each().